# How to dynamically define struct content in GO from reading a json file

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm trying to create a go struct for my project. I want the struct content to be defined in a separate JSON file, as example below :

```
{
    "structA":{
          "column_name" :["id","name","occupation","age"],
          "column_type" :["int","string","string","int"]
}
```

And when we compile go, the struct will be somehow like

```
type structA struct {
    id int
    name string
    occupation string
    age int
}
```

I want the structA definition to be written in a way like looping though the json and generate it afterwards. Is it possible to do so in Go?

Comment: Go is a statically typed and compiled language. You could generate the code and compile it after. Maps and slices are probably a much better fit for dynamic data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON schema to define your types and generate Go code with your types using this package: https://github.com/idubinskiy/schematyper